# How to check whether selection is present in the span or not in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id='QuestionText'>
  <p>This is a simple example </p>
  <span> I am asking the question </span>
</div>
```

I am getting the html contents of div in the following line

> var existing_lesson = $('#QuestionText').html();

I am getting the 'the question' as my selection in the following line

> var getselectedarea = $.selection();

Now I want to find whether the selection is present in the span element or not means if I select the `simple example` as my selection I should get that it is present in which html tag and if I select `the question` as my selection I should get that it is present in the which html tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
var foundInSpan = $("#QuestionText > span").text().indexOf(text) > -1;

var foundInP = $("#QuestionText > p").text().indexOf(text) > -1;
```

---

or you could use `grep` to find all of the tags that contain that text:

```
var tags = $("#QuestionText").children().grep(
    function(){
        return $element.text().indexOf(text) > -1;
    });
```

Comment: Why do not use the ":contains" statement in that case ? Performances issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it (as an alternative to hunter's `indexOf` approach) is with a regex `.test()`:

```
var foundInSpan = new RegExp(text).test($("#QuestionText > span").text());
```

jsPerf shows the performance to be more or less a wash:  http://jsperf.com/find-text-test